# the type is not registered as safe custom task form

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, tasks

I have built state machine workflow which uses custom task form. The custom task form is based on custom content type. When I try to open custom task form I get below error:

> The base type 'Project.Taskform' is not allowed for this page. The type is not registered as safe.

My package manifest file looks like below:

```
<pre>
Assemblies

Assembly Location="Project.dll" DeploymentTarget="GlobalAssemblyCache" /

  Assemblies
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the safe control in your Manifest.xml file.This is because SharePoint must be aware that the types within the assembly we are deploying are safe and ok to execute.

```
 <Assemblies>
 <Assembly DeploymentTarget="WebApplication" Location="SharePointCodeBehindPages.dll"> 
<SafeControls> 
<SafeControl Namespace="Name of namespace" Safe="True" TypeName="*" /> 
</SafeControls> 
</Assembly>
 </Assemblies>
```

Read more at http://www.andrewconnell.com/Using-ASPNET-2-0-Code-Behind-Files-in-SharePoint-v3-Sites#8SZdY42Sm5u4rPRB.99